# Accesing 2 different websites with SSL (https) and one single static IP from provider

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, centos, apache-http-server

Situation: 2 dedicated LAMP servers (CentOS + Ubuntu), one static IP Address, one router.

First server internal IP : 192.168.0.60 - Web hosting server

Ports forwarded in router configuration: 21, 22, 80, 443, 993, 465, etc

Second server internal IP: 192.168.0.61 - File sharing server - Owncloud

Ports forwarded in router configuration: 8001 (i've changed Apache2 to listen to this port), 2222(i've changed sshd to listen to this port) and 54 (changed BIND to listen to this port).
All those ports were changed because they are already in use by the first server.  ​

If i enter a website from the first server in address bar all works ok and also https (secured connection)

If i enter hostname of the second server in address bar (eg. http://hostname.domain.com:8001/owncloud) everything works ok, Owncloud interface is loading, i can login, etc.

How can i make it work with https considering that 443 is allready forwarded to first server (in router config).

I've tried changing the listen port to 444 in Apache ssl.conf and then foward that port in router config, but i cannot make it work.
I've also tried to root 443 to 444 in the second server with iptables but no succes.

Any advice will be apreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already run Apache on the first server and you have (presumably) already setup SSL for that you can use that same apache instance to [reverse-proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#examples) to the second server.

It is also worth knowing that you can have a fully functional HTTPS site on the non-default port, although some firewalls may block access to such ports.

For your specific case it could be done by adding this to your ssl configuration of apache on server 1:

```
ProxyPass "/owncloud" "http://192.168.0.61/"
ProxyPassReverse "/owncloud" "http://192.168.0.61"
```

Make sure to also check the documentation for how to install&enable the required `mod_proxy` modules.

On NGINX you can achieve that by adding this endpoint to the http config

```
location /ownclouf/ {
    proxy_pass http://192.168.0.61/;
}
```

Comment: Apache works on second server only if i put :8001 after the hostname set up in /etc/hostname and in /etc/hosts (eg. http://hostname.com:8001/owncloud). 8001 is set in ports.conf in /etc/apache2/.The login screen of the owncloud appears in browser. But when i hit htttps://hostname.com:8001/owncloud it gives me "ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR".

I guess the error is that SSL is listening on the first server, so regarding de browser standards when an adress is inserted in the addres bar with https the port that is calling is 443, wich is listen on the first server and forwarded in the router config.

Comment: So i have to make https work also on the second server.

Comment: Right, but am I correct to assume that public port 443 is forwarded to the first server? And do you have SSL configured there?

Comment: Yes, i have allready configured there the 443 port. All the websites hosted there have secured connection if i put https in front.

Comment: I see. Then you can do what I described above. It will basically forward/proxy all requests arriving as HTTPS on server 1 via HTTP to server 2.

Comment: The requests would get to server 2 as follows: Client GET https://hostname.domain.com/owncloud -> port forwarding -> 192.168.0.60:443 -> apache proxies based on the path /owncloud -> GET http://192.168.0.61:8000

Comment: So as far as i understand i have to make a reverse proxy on the first server in default-ssl.conf of the Apache


Something like:

<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerName hostname.com (second server)
    
SSLEngine On
    
SSLProxyEngine On
    
ProxyRequests Off
    
ProxyPreserveHost On

ProxyHTMLInterp On
    
ProxyHTMLExtended On
    
ProxyHTMLURLMap (.*)192.168.0.61(.*) https://hostname.com$2 [Rin] (second server) 
    
ProxyPass / https://192.168.0.61/ 
    
ProxyPassReverse / https://192.168.0.61/

Comment: How cand i make that? Or how should i google it to solve the problem? What terms do i have to find?

Comment: Hey, I edited my original answer to give you a more complete answer to your specific question. If you want a more guided documentation try searching for "apache2 https reverse-proxy"

Comment: My first server have Nginx , i have to find a solution for Nginx, your's is an Apache solution.

Comment: See the update above

Comment: I've tried your solution.
When i hit http://hosntame.com:8001/owncloud (http in front) sites loads 
When i hit https://hostname.com:8001/owncloud(https in front)it gives me ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Comment: I've solved it ! Now if i hit hostname.com/owncloud with https in front it loads the default interface of the owncloud but it gives me certificate error (certificate not valid). Your connection isn;t secure. Know as far as i understand i have to install a certificate with let's encrypt on the second server, right?

Comment: No, the idea was to configure SSL only on the first server and proxy from there via http to the unencrypted owncloud on server 2. Can you confirm that SSL works on server 1 otherwise? And that you configured the reverse proxying from server 1 to server 2 using plain http?